# Prove that $ \text{H}^1(G/P,\text{Z}(P)) = 0 $ for a normal Sylow p-subgroup P

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $ p $ be a prime and $ G $ a (multiplicatively written) finite group with a normal Sylow $ p $-subgroup. Let $ Q = G/P $. Then $ Q $ acts on $ \text{Z}(P) $ via conjugation: $ gP.z = gzg^{-1} $.
With this group operation $ \text{Z}(P) $ becomes a $ Q $-module.
Now my question is, how can I prove, that $ \text{H}^1(Q,\text{Z}(P) = 0 $?

Clearly $ Q $ is a $ p' $-group. I tried to show that any $ \mathbb{Z}Q $-module homomorphism
from $ \mathbb{Z}Q $ to $ \text{Z}(P) $ is trivial but failed until now.

Comment: It is a standard result that $H^n(G,V)=0$ for any $n \ge 1$ whenever $|G|$ and $|V|$ are coprime.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! Do you have any hint for me how to prove it? I mean, are there any non-trivial module homomorphism? Then I would need to show directly, that the cochain of morphism groups is exact for $ n \geq 1 $...

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ (of finite index), then the restriction $H^n(G,V) \to H^n(H,V)$ followed by the corestriction $H^n(H,V) \to H^n(G,V)$ is equal to multiplication by the index $|G:H|$. So if $|G:H|$ is coprime to the exponent of $V$, then this composite is an isomorphism, and so the restriction map is injective. In your case, put $H=1$, and we have an injective map $H^n(G,V) \to H^n(H,V) = 0$, so $H^n(G,V)=0$.